# Res.send proceed before Function Model.find() Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I got the problem when trying to find the value throw 2 model

```
.get(function(req, res) {
        var sellerPosts = [];
        Product.find({seller_id : req.params.seller_id}, function(err, products) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                console.log("id", products[i].id);
                Post.find({product_id : products[i].id}, function(err, posts) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    for (var j = 0; j < posts.length; j++) {
                        sellerPosts.push(posts[j]);
                        console.log("in find",sellerPosts);

                    }
                });
                console.log(sellerPosts);
            }
            console.log("test", sellerPosts);

            res.send(sellerPosts);
        });

    })
```

This is the log :

```
App listening on port 3000!
Connected to database
id 58ea96464429aa154cb8c43a
[]
id 58ed3171a0cc7f20f4c74c1c
[]
test []
in find [ { _id: 58ed28b8993a2317e41fc742,
    product_id: 58ea96464429aa154cb8c43a,
    phone: 9123123,
    address: 'hanhitie17',
    other: 'no others',
    __v: 0 } ]
in find [ { _id: 58ed28b8993a2317e41fc742,
    product_id: 58ea96464429aa154cb8c43a,
    phone: 9123123,
    address: 'hanhitie17',
    other: 'no others',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 58ed33cea0cc7f20f4c74c1d,
    product_id: 58ed3171a0cc7f20f4c74c1c,
    phone: 9123123,
    address: 'hanhitie17',
    other: 'no others',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

The first sellerPosts still print out true values but the "test" log is empty.
After doing some log. I think it is because after the first for in Product.find(), the program run the res.send and then run the Post.find(). 
Help me on fixing this problem please!!!!

Comment: You should take a look at the `async` module for node, especially the `async.each` (http://caolan.github.io/async/)

Comment: or just call `res.send` when `i === products.length` inside your callback. The async module works great and so do promises, but you should know how your control flow works before using either of those packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `Post.find` in a loop which is causing problem since it is an async operation you need to make it sequential. You can do it using async library as in the below code.

```
.get(function(req, res) {
        var sellerPosts = [];
        Product.find({seller_id : req.params.seller_id}, function(err, products) {
            if (err) throw err;
            async.eachSeries(products, function(product, next){
                Post.find({product_id : product.id}, function(err, posts) {
                    if (err) next(err);
                    for (var j = 0; j < posts.length; j++) {
                        sellerPosts.push(posts[j]);
                        console.log("in find",sellerPosts);
                    }
                    next(null);
                });
            }, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send(sellerPosts);
            })
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes response returns before `Post.find` finishes and this is right behaviour because javascript is asynchronous you should use [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)

So I rewrited your code using promises:

```
.get((req, res) => {

  Product.find({ seller_id: req.params.seller_id })
  .then(products => {

    let postPromises = products.map(product => {
      return Post.find({ product_id: product.id });
    });

    return Promise.all(postPromises);
  })
  .then(posts => {
    let sellerPosts = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], posts);

    res.json(sellerPosts);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });

});
```

Comment: Why promisejs? If I'm not mistaken, promisejs is meant for both the front and back-end. [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) is the fastest back-end promise library as far as I know... But for people just starting out, NodeJS 4.x and above support native promises, so you don't even need a 3rd party package.

Comment: As you see I use native promise of node.js, I linked promisejs because It has good docs and will easily understand what is promises and how to use it

Comment: I have use the code above but it have the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>" I had install the promise and also a local variable. I did upgrade my nodejs version

Comment: type `sudo node -v` if your nodejs version isn't latest stable use these commans to update it:
`sudo npm cache clean -f` , 
`sudo npm install -g n` , 
`sudo n stable`
then try use this code

Comment: I can not run the  npm install -g n . Windows_NT 6.3.9600

Comment: You use old nodejs version which doesn't support es6 features